# DotNetNuke.Entities.Urls.UrlRewriterUtils - System.ArgumentNullException

Tags: asp.net, webforms, dotnetnuke

Working on a DNN (9.2) module and am getting the following error in the DNN log file when trying to call `http://dnndev.me/desktopmodules/rentalz/server.ashx` directly from URL address bar in browser:

```
        DotNetNuke.Entities.Urls.UrlRewriterUtils - System.ArgumentNullException: 
        Value cannot be null.
        Parameter name: url
        at System.Web.HttpResponse.Redirect(String url, 
        Boolean endResponse, Boolean permanent)    
        at DotNetNuke.Entities.Urls.AdvancedUrlRewriter.ProcessRequest(
        HttpContext context, Uri requestUri, Boolean useFriendlyUrls,
        UrlAction result, FriendlyUrlSettings settings, 
        Boolean allowSettingsChange, Guid parentTraceId)
```

When I remove the following entry from the Web.config file, the ASHX page works, but the rest of the site bombs out!

```
<add name="UrlRewrite" type="DotNetNuke.HttpModules.UrlRewriteModule,
    DotNetNuke.HttpModules" preCondition="managedHandler" />
```

Does anyone know what's causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This request shouldn't be handled by the URL rewriter, it ignores `ashx` requests by default.  You can go to the SEO Settings page, and check the *Expressions* tab under *URL Management* to see if `ashx` is listed in the *Do Not Rewrite URL Regular Expression*.  You can also go the the *Test URL* tab and put your URL in to see what sort of rewriting the system is trying to perform.

Comment: This is what I'm seeing:
/DesktopModules/|/Providers/|/LinkClick\.aspx|/profilepic\.ashx|/DnnImageHandler\.ashx|/__browserLink/|/API/
Can you suggest the edit needed?

Comment: Actually, I just copied the settings for this from the live server to my local and it worked. Thx so much!

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use a handler anymore. It's an old technique that can easily create security flaws on your website.  You should instead us Web API.  It's so much easier to do as well.

http://www.dnnsoftware.com/wiki/services-framework-webapi

Comment: Agreed, but this is a maintenance task for an existing application. No time for a rewrite.

Comment: I took a look - practically zero documentation. My gut is to take the apps out of DNN and stay as far from it as possible.

Comment: I don't know why anyone would expect for a technique this old to be documented for any software solution.